# Why maven swagger plugin isn't scanning external modules?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger, swagger-2.0

We have a maven multimodule project which looks approximatively like that:

```
Parent
    - admin
    - microserviceA 
    - microserviceB
    - microserviceC
```

The microservices A, B and C expose functional specific rest endpoints.
However, the admin module exposes common rest endpoints for resilience, robustness and recovery.

In order to document our APIs, we are using swagger 2.0 with the maven swagger plugin.

The `pom.xml` that we are using for each microservice looks like:

**MicroserviceA:**

```
<build>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiSources>
                        <apiSource>
                            <springmvc>false</springmvc>
                            <locations>
                                    <location>com.xxx.a.resource</location> 
                                    <location>com.xxx.admin.resource</location>
                            </locations>
                            <schemes>http,https</schemes>
.....
</build>
```

**MicroserviceB:**

```
<build>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiSources>
                        <apiSource>
                            <springmvc>false</springmvc>
                            <locations>
                                    <location>com.xxx.b.resource</location> 
                                    <location>com.xxx.admin.resource</location>
                            </locations>
                            <schemes>http,https</schemes>
.....
</build>
```

**MicroserviceC:**

```
<build>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${swagger.maven.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <apiSources>
                            <apiSource>
                                <springmvc>false</springmvc>
                                <locations>
                                        <location>com.xxx.c.resource</location> 
                                        <location>com.xxx.admin.resource</location>
                                </locations>
                                <schemes>http,https</schemes>
    .....
    </build>
```

**Problem :** The maven plugin isn't scanning the rest endpoints at the admin module level even by specifying explicitly the admin package in the maven swagger plugin `<location>`.

**PS:** I've tried several version of maven plugin.

Is there any solution?

Comment: If admin itself is an independent service, i don't really understand why its specs needs to be generated as part of other microservices.  If its not an independent service, then you should declare it as dependency in other miscroservices you have mentioned.

Comment: Each microservice is organized around business capabilities, autonomously developed, independently deployable, decentralized wheras the admin modules is nothing but several reusable non-functional requirements which will decorates every microservice spec by a number of endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that’s a limitation in the swagger plugin since several issues are opened in the their Git with no answers. (Since 2017)